# How to update a property for all dataclass objects in a list?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a list of objects of the following type:

```
@dataclass
class Feature:
    name: str
    active: bool
```

and my list is:

```
features = [Feature("name1",False), Feature("name2",False), Feature("name3",True)]
```

I want to get back a list with all the features but switch their `active` property to `True`. I tried to use `map()` like this:

```
active_features=list(map(lambda f: f.active=True,features))
```

but it gives me an error `expected parameter`. How can this be achieved?

***Note*** *I thought it was following from the example, but I guess I should have clarified. I want to do this with some short of inline method, without defining a new separate function as suggested from some of the answers, but maybe it cannot be done like this?*

Comment: Do you want a list of *new* instances, or do you want to modify the existing instances in-place?

Comment: `lambda` takes expressions, not statements. An assignment is a statement so it doesn't work. You can't really use list-comprehension as well as your goal is to change the state not create a new list. Do you want a list of new objects with their state switched, or do you simply want to switch the state of the original objects?

Comment: @chepner I dont mind either way

Comment: @KZiovas You probably should.

Comment: @chepner why should I mind? I just want to use this in a pytest.

Comment: Because if you change the objects in place and have other references to the object somewhere else, you may be surprised when they change.

Comment: yeah of course but this is not always an issue and this was the point of my answer. In this case I dont mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reason why your logic is not working?

It gives you error because the `lambda` function you're using is trying to modify the value of `f.active`, **which is not allowed in a lambda function**. `lambda` functions are allowed to only for **expressions that return a value, rather than statements that perform some actions.**

So I think one way to do it like below-

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import copy

@dataclass
class Feature:
    name: str
    active: bool


features = [Feature("name1",False), Feature("name2",False), Feature("name3",True)]
active_features = []
main_features = copy.deepcopy(features)
for f in main_features:
    f.active = True
    active_features.append(f)
print(active_features)
print(features)
```

**Output:**

```
[Feature(name='name1', active=True), Feature(name='name2', active=True), Feature(name='name3', active=True)]

[Feature(name='name1', active=False), Feature(name='name2', active=False), Feature(name='name3', active=True)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call dataclasses' [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace) which will create a copy with the changed attribute:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, replace

@dataclass
class Feature:
    name: str
    active: bool
             
features = [Feature("used-to-be", False), Feature("maybe", False)]
active_features = [replace(x, active=True) for x in features]

print(active_features) # should be active
print(features) # should be intact
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy modifying the instances in place, there's no need to build a new list. Just use a regular `for` loop.

```
features = [Feature("name1",False), Feature("name2",False), Feature("name3",True)]

for f in features:
    f.active = True
```

If you want a list of *new* objects, leaving the original objects unchanged, I would still use a regular `for` loop:

```
new_features = []
for f in features:
    new_features.append(Feature(f.name, True))
```

though adding an instance method that can create an active feature from an existing feature would make things cleaner:

```
@dataclass
class Feature:
    name: str
    active: bool

    def make_new_active(self):
        return type(self)(self.name, True)

features = [...]
new_features = [f.make_new_active() for f in features]
```

(Though note: I am basically reimplementing `dataclasses.replace`, which I forgot about. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74852093/1126841 instead.)

Comment: I like the latter approach, my only concern is it might get out of hands to manage when the list of attributes starts to expand.

Comment: Liked you idea to solve the problem sir.

Comment: It's basically your answer; I just forgot that `dataclasses.replace` exists :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method on the original class.

```
@dataclass
class Feature:
    name: str
    active:bool
    def activate(self):
        self.active =True                                                 
        return self
                                                          
features = [Feature("name1",False), Feature("name2",False), Feature("name3",True)]

active_features=list(map(lambda f: f.activate(),features))                  

active_features

[Feature(name='name1', active=True), Feature(name='name2', active=True), Feature(name='name3', active=True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to do this using `map` you can not use lambda because lambda can only have expressions not assignments. Also it has to return something as well. Do this instead

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Feature:
    name: str
    active: bool
    
def activate_feature(feature: Feature):
        feature.active = True
        return feature


features = [Feature("name1",False), Feature("name2",False), Feature("name3",True)]

active_features = list(map(activate_feature, features))
print(active_features)
```

Output

```
[Feature(name='name1', active=True), Feature(name='name2', active=True), Feature(name='name3', active=True)]
```

Or if you want to go with lambda as well you can do this as well

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Feature:
    name: str
    active: bool
    
    def activate(self):
        self.active = True
        return self

features = [Feature("name1", False), Feature("name2", False), Feature("name3", True)]

active_features = list(map(lambda f: f.activate(), features))
print(active_features)
```

Output

```
[Feature(name='name1', active=True), Feature(name='name2', active=True), Feature(name='name3', active=True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the data in the old list:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from copy import deepcopy

@dataclass
class Feature:
    name: str
    active: bool

features = [Feature("name1",False), Feature("name2",False), Feature("name3",True)]

for feature in features:
    feature.active = True
print(features)
# [Feature(name='name1', active=True), Feature(name='name2', active=True), Feature(name='name3', active=True)]
```

Or make a new list of modified values:

```
def func(feature):
    feature.active = True
    return feature
active_features = list(map(func, deepcopy(features)))

print(active_features)
# [Feature(name='name1', active=True), Feature(name='name2', active=True), Feature(name='name3', active=True)]

# If you try to print the original list, You can see that the element in the original does not change.

print(features)
# [Feature(name='name1', active=False), Feature(name='name2', active=False), Feature(name='name3', active=True)]
```

---

In the lambda function you can't use the assignment operator `=`.